# Jquery Slider: make part of it available?

Tags: jquery, slider

I've got a jquery slider for selecting a deposit term (in a bank). For the most of the deposit types term range is 1-36 months, but for one of them - only 1-12.

I want to keep the interface uniform (36 months slider) but make unavailable term unselectable (it shouldn't be possible to slide to higher values than 12). As a result, the slider should have max=36, but you can slide to maximum value = 12.

Is it possible in any way?  Simple or tricky - doesn't matter, but the simplier is of course the better.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not "snap it back"? if slider value > 12 bring it back to 12 with a UI message showing up under the slider "capped at 12"?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a way to 'partially' disable the slider...

Comment: 'snap it back' - 
thanks, I will keep it as an option, but I would like to avoid  event-fired methods (frequent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 36,
    value: 12,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
       if(ui.value > 12)
           return false;
       $value.text(ui.value);
    }
});
```

It wont allow the slider to go ahead of 12.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/3QVUf/160/

Comment: I did it like this: ... if (ui.value>12) ui.value=12 ...; but your solution is more elegant.

Comment: Thanks. The funny part is I had used it extensively for a project, still I had to google for it

Comment: This is quite usual for me too :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the text from 13 - 36 to be a slightly dimmer color, to make it look like it is disabled, and then use the jump back method ass suggested.

I did try the Snap it back method.
http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/aLJQm/52/

The Slider snaps back, but the reported value is still higher than 12.

Only need to do the numbering bit now...

Comment: Thank you for your input, but this is not exactly what I was for. Everything should be uniform, i.e. look the same, but function a bit differently.